# Store String Character in a Jagged Array

Tags: c#, string, jagged-arrays

I have a string and want to store every word characters in this string in a jagged array without using a split() method, just loops. I tried this code but it didnt work,i want the result will be something like that:

```
sepwords[0][1] = {H,e,l,l,o};
sepwords[0][2] = {h,o,w};
sepwords[0][3] = {a,r,e};
sepwords[0][4] = {y,o,u};
```

The code i tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    letters[i] = text[i];
}

foreach (char item in letters)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (letters[i] != ',' || letters[i] != ';' || letters[i] != '!' || letters[i] != '?' || letters[i] != '.' || letters[i] != ' ')
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
            {
                sepwords[0] = new char[length];
                sepwords[0][j] = letters[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sepwords[0] = new char[length];`

You're overwriting every array with a new one when you reach a new word.

Comment: but i tried without this line and got :
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Well.  Yes.  Because you didn't initialize anything.  The key thing to keep in mind is that you're accessing `sepwords[0]` every time.  What about `sepwords[1]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this..

```
char[][] sepwords = new char[4][];
sepwords[0] = "Hello".ToCharArray();
sepwords[1] = "how".ToCharArray();
sepwords[2] = "are".ToCharArray();
sepwords[3] = "you".ToCharArray();
```